# How are we supposed to run joins in bigquery when you have to specify the dataset with the table name?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can't run a query like:

```
SELECT table1.name FROM dataset1.table1
```

nor can I run

```
SELECT dataset1.table1.name FROM dataset1.table1
```

So I can't even begin to play with joins. How are we supposed to run joins in bigquery when you have to specify the dataset with the table name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Jordan, that's what I was doing wrong. I'm used to mySQL where that select would work fine but in BQ that doesn't work. Once I wrote out the entire join the table names were picked up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this:

```
SELECT table1.name1, table1.name2, table2.name1, table2.name2
FROM dataset.table1 as table1
JOIN dataset.table2 as table2
ON table1.name1 = table2.name1
WHERE table1.name1 = whatever
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Error: Unknown field: table1.name1 - the select doesn't seem to accept the AS name assigned.

Comment: Could you paste your table's schema please?

Comment: Note that fully-qualified table names only work in a join query. If you are just trying them out in a simple single-table select (as you do in your question) they will not work -- you need to just specify the field name (not table.field).